# Is Weizenbock a good style to cellar?

Tags: cellaring

I always thought that it was a great beer to cellar for a year or more. I have a full keg and about a case of bottles of it on hand though. Wheat tells me it doesn't age well. Decent amount of alcohol, melanoidins, and a reference to an optional 'sherry' character from the BJCP guidelines tells me it does.

Comment: I've only brewed it once, but that batch did age well. I'll leave it to someone with more experience to post an answer, but I would assume yes, it is good for cellaring.

Answer (score 2):

These are the general criteria I use when determining if I should cellar a beer:

- Alcohol: The higher the alcohol content the better results from cellaring. A Weizenbock would be fine in this case.
- Flavor: Is there a big aggressive flavor up front that ruins all the other flavor? A good example is an IPA like Dogfish 120, when the aggressive sweetness dies down over time. I am not sure about a Weizenbock in this respect. Maybe if there is a heavy banana flavor it will be more balanced as the esters degrade.
- Body: Generally, I find a heavier bodied beer ages better. I am sure there is some chemistry behind this, say esters degrading or dextrin doing whatever dextrin does. That said, many bocks are not super heavy-bodied but do well with 1-2 years of aging.

I realize that is not a yes/no answer but I hope it helps.